# Mariadb match against a view fails; succeeds in MySql

Tags: full-text-search, match, mariadb, fulltext-index

The fulltext search query below fails in mariadb, but succeeds in mysql (mariadb database imported from mysql database using phpmyadmin).

If a base table is substituted, the query succeeds in both mariadb and mysql. So apparently mariadb cannot match against views.

Is there a solution to this? It's messing up my migration.

Thanks.

SELECT`Title` FROM `Nodes_View` WHERE (MATCH(`Title`,`Caption`,`Description`,`Location`,`Body`) AGAINST('something'))

Comment: Please provide (for _both_ cases) the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW CREATE VIEW`.  Then file a bug report with MariaDB.  Also include a value for 'something' that fails.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I filed a bug here https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-8645, and it's been confirmed and assigned.